# Random Sampling in R: Limiting Number of Repetitions

Tags: r

I have the following vector in R: z = c(1,3,5,7,9,11).

I am wishing to randomly sample from this vector 4 elements at a time, but such that no more than 2 elements repeat. I.e.,

```
sample(z,4,replace=T) = (1,1,3,11)
sample(z,4,replace=T) = (1,5,5,9)
```

but not

```
sample(z,4,replace=T) = (1,1,1,11)
```

And so on.

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that's `sample(rep(z, 2L), 4L)`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Good answer.  Why not write it up as an answer?

Comment: @G5W TBH I just thought of it quickly but I'm not 100% sure it's accurate and haven't had time to assure myself of that (which I would want to do if writing up more officially)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Looks perfect to me.

Comment: Hi. Thanks! That worked great. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The answer by @MichaelChirico seems right. I rewrite it with some explanations,

```
z <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11)  
sample(
  rep(z, 
      times = 2L  # times = 2L doubles the vector z
      ),
  size = 4L,  # it determines the number of items to choose
  replace = FALSE  # this is default but it makes no more than 2 elements repeated
)
```

By choosing FALSE for *replace* argument in your own code "sample(z, 4, replace=T)" ,
it returns no repeats at all.